# What causes Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap

Tags: c++

When I run my program it throws error:

```
invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00530000, 00A39B18 )
```

I think it's because of realloc but I can't understand why. And I must use malloc, realloc and free instead of new and delete.
My .h file:

```
#pragma once

class String
{
private:
    char* mas;
    int n;
public:
    String();
    void EmptyStr();
    void print();
    void operator = (char* str);
    void operator = (const String &a);
    String operator+ (char* str);
    String operator + (const String &a);
    void operator += (char*);
    void operator += (const String &a);
    char &operator [] (int i);
};
```

My .cpp file:

```
#include"Strings.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

String::String()
{
    this->mas = NULL;
    this->n = 0;
}

void String::print()
{
    std::cout << this->mas << ' ' << this->n << std::endl;
}

void String::EmptyStr()
{
    this->mas = (char*)realloc(this->mas, sizeof(char));
    this->n = 0;
    this->mas[0] = '\0';
}

void String::operator =(char* str)
{
    this->n = strlen(str);
    this->mas = (char*)realloc(this->mas, (this->n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    this->mas = str;
}

void String::operator=(const String &a)
{
    this->mas = (char*)realloc(this->mas, (a.n + 1)* sizeof(char));
    this->n = a.n;
    *this = a.mas;
}

String String::operator+(char* str)
{
    String tmp;
    tmp.mas = (char*)malloc((this->n + strlen(str)+1) * sizeof(char));
    tmp.n = this->n + strlen(str);
    tmp.mas[0] = '\0';
    strcat(tmp.mas, this->mas);
    strcat(tmp.mas, str);
    return tmp;
}

String String::operator+(const String &a)
{
    String tmp;
    tmp.mas = (char*)malloc((this->n + a.n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    tmp.n = this->n + a.n;
    tmp = *this + a.mas;
    return tmp;
}

void String::operator+=(char* str)
{
    *this = *this + str;
}
```

And my main .cpp file

```
#include"Strings.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    String a, b, c;
    a = "Hello";
    b = "ASD";
    b = a;
    b.print();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I really can't understand what is wrong, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
this->mas = (char*)realloc(this->mas, (this->n + 1) * sizeof(char));
this->mas = str;
```

The first line allocates memory, and makes `mas` point to that newly allocated memory. The second line makes `mas` point somewhere else completely. Here you should not just assign the pointer to point somewhere else, but *copy* the string using e.g. [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

With the code you have now, when you do

```
b = "ASD";
```

you make `b.mas` point to the first character in the string literal. Then when you do

```
b = a;
```

you use the pointer to the string literal in the `realloc` call, which is wrong since you have not allocated that memory through `malloc` or `realloc`.

---

On another note, you should never assign right back to the pointer you passed to `realloc`. If `realloc` fails and returns a null pointer, you lose the original pointer and will have a memory leak.